# Selenium RC in Ubuntu doesn't start Firefox 2 (and cannot close it)

Tags: php, automated-tests, selenium-rc, ubuntu-10.10, selenium-grid

I'm using selenium grid and I have tried both server versions 1.0.3 and now replaced with 2.2.0. It works fine with google chrome and opera, but with **firefox 2** or 3.6.9 it fails.

So with bad case scenario grid has configuration with

```
name:    "Ubuntu - Firefox 2"
browser: "*firefox /home/artjom/opt/firefox-2.0/firefox-bin"
```

And running testCase stops at loading profiles

```
     [java] 15:41:12.103 INFO - Command request: getNewBrowserSession[*firefox /home/artjom/opt/firefox-2.0/firefox-bin, http://kurapov.name/] on session null
     [java] 15:41:12.104 INFO - creating new remote session
     [java] 15:41:12.104 INFO - Allocated session 1bae135617ab4761abd6be894e49bdae for http://kurapov.name/, launching...
     [java] 15:41:12.215 INFO - Preparing Firefox profile...
     [java] 15:41:20.345 INFO - Checking connection to hub...
     [java] 15:41:20.345 INFO - Ping Hub at http://192.168.20.106:4444/heartbeat?host=192.168.20.98&port=5555
     [java] 15:41:32.540 ERROR - Failed to start new browser session, shutdown browser and clear all session data
     [java] java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out waiting for profile to be created!
     [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.waitForFullProfileToBeCreated(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:360)
```

And if i try adding some extra params in there like -P default or -no-remote, then its not parsed correctly. So instead i can write a shell script that does same thing, although in config I'l have to use *custom instead of *firefox and i think it affects somehow how browser is closed..

```
name:    "Ubuntu - Firefox 2"
browser: "*custom /home/artjom/firefox2.sh"
```

So now all of the sudden it works fine, except that browser is not closed at the end of the session, causing problems with recurrent execution. And `close()` method at the end of the test case (or teardown) that many suggest only closes page that is being tested, while RC execution frame remains. Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens when you try just *firefox?

Comment: Well it doesn't know where firefox2 is.. it starts firefox 5.. which starts doing plugin/addon update check, even though its disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partially solved by using *firefoxproxy that does close browser and by using default profile